# PySpark combine two or more dataframe with condition

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have multiple spark dataframes `df1,df2,df3` with below schema

```
--- X (float)
--- Y (float)
--- id (String)
```

Now I want to merge all of them such that

- if `df1.X == df2.X and df1.Y == df2.Y then concat(df1.id,df2.id)`
- put this as single row in resultant `df`
- else put both as different rows in resultant `df`

Is there a way I can do so using joins or lambdas in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data

```scala
 val df1 = spark.range(4).withColumn("x", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("id")) * lit(1f))
    df1.show(false)
    /**
      * +---+---+
      * |id |x  |
      * +---+---+
      * |0  |1.0|
      * |1  |2.0|
      * |2  |3.0|
      * |3  |4.0|
      * +---+---+
      */
    val df2 = spark.range(2).withColumn("x", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("id")) * lit(1f))
    df2.show(false)
    /**
      * +---+---+
      * |id |x  |
      * +---+---+
      * |0  |1.0|
      * |1  |2.0|
      * +---+---+
      */
```

### Merge Common and uncommon records

```scala
    val inner = df1.join(df2, Seq("x"))
      .select(
        $"x", concat(df1("id"), df2("id")).as("id")
      )
    val commonPlusUncommon =
      df1.join(df2, Seq("x"), "leftanti")
        .unionByName(
          df2.join(df1, Seq("x"), "leftanti")
        ).unionByName(inner)
    commonPlusUncommon.show(false)

    /**
      * +---+---+
      * |x  |id |
      * +---+---+
      * |3.0|2  |
      * |4.0|3  |
      * |1.0|00 |
      * |2.0|11 |
      * +---+---+
      */
```

### You can also use full outer join

```scala
 df1.join(df2, Seq("x"), "full")
      .select(
        $"x",
        concat(coalesce(df1("id"), lit("")), coalesce(df2("id"), lit(""))).as("id")
      )
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+---+
      * |x  |id |
      * +---+---+
      * |1.0|00 |
      * |2.0|11 |
      * |3.0|2  |
      * |4.0|3  |
      * +---+---+
      */
```